# I can't build my first empty project with android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, compilation

recentely i have installed android studio but i can't build an empty project! where is the problem?!!
find bellow the Sync issue details

> ```html
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1.
>
> Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1.
> Required by:
>     project :app
>  > Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1.
>     > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/test/runner/1.0.1/runner-1.0.1.pom'.
>           > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/test/runner/1.0.1/runner-1.0.1.pom'.
>                    > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>                                > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>                                               > unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> ```

Comment: are you able to download the pom file using a normal browser? link: `https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/test/runner/1.0.1/runner-1.0.1.pom`

Comment: no ! I can't ..there is a 404 error

Comment: It seems your project is not building because it needs to download that file. Here I'm able to download, so I guess it is some internet problem.

Comment: you can try to remove the test in gradle.build

Answer (score 1):

you can try to remove all test file in gradle.build (app) inside dependencies, it looks like this

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
```

the problem maybe because of your internet connection and make it can't download the file.

Comment: it seems that it's not the only problem !

Comment: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.

Comment: have you check, **Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle** is on offline work or not? maybe you can try to turn it off if its on

Comment: Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No cached version listing for com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+ available for offline mode.